# Why can we hear above 8 kHz

Tags: human-biology, evolution

Why have humans developed ears capable of hearing sounds that are (never?) heard in nature.

Is it known why humans developed the ability to hear up to 20 kHz when all the relevant noises are below 8 kHz? (at least in my experience) Or why was it beneficial to hear in that range?

Comment: Your question seems to be based on a false premise, because indeed there are sounds in nature >8kHz, including sounds at higher frequency than human hearing (for example, mice vocalize up to 60 kHz or so).

Comment: @BryanKrause Yes of course there are some sounds but why would it be beneficial for us to hear them?

Comment: @user1136 How does that help with sounds that aren't in high frequency ranges? Doesn't this only work with very high frequencies? How is it helpful for a human to localize mice and other small animals?

Comment: Sounds in nature aren't usually pure tones.  They have overtones at higher frequencies, and these are very important in distinguishing between sounds.  Think of several musical instruments all playing the same note: you can readily tell the difference between a piano, a violin, and a trumpet, can't you?

Comment: @jamesqf But why don't you hear the tone that's over 8 kHz only the part of the tone that is deeper? Or do you?

Comment: You do hear those tones - that is, the ear reacts to them.  But the brain interprets them as a single sound instead of separating them into pure tones.  Similarly, the eye has just 3 color receptors (for most people): the brain combines signals from them to produce the 10 million or so different colors that a human can distinguish, but you don't see the separate RGB signals.